# Is checking the parshios a hefsek?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilin, hefsek-interruption, inspection

Are you required to make another bracha on your tefillin if you take them off to check the parshios?

Comment: I'm 99% sure the Yalkut Yosef says it's not a Hefsek.

Answer (score 4):

The Biur Halacha says you must make a new *beracha* because since you make the tefilin invalid in the process of checking the *parshiyos* this is considered a *hefsek* (interruption) in the mitzvah.

Comment: The Biur Halacha says he is in doubt whether you can compare the above case to the strap breaking since if the strap breaks it is still called tefilin even though it is pasul to wear, but by tefilin- there is no more tefilin.  He concludes with tzarich iyun.

Comment: Biur Halacha: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=69

Answer (score 0):

With tefilin, if you had in mind when putting them on that you might be taking them off and later putting them back on; then as long as you weren't in a situation in the middle that you COULDN'T have worn tefilin, the original bracha covers it.

So bathroom breaks require a new bracha.  If you took them off for five minutes to help carry suitcases, you wouldn't need a new bracha.

Certainly wherever you're checking your tefilin is a place where tefilin can be worn; but I wonder if there's enough of a pause and concentration needed to open and check tefilin if you can still have that in mind.  But in theory yes.

Comment: "So bathroom breaks require a new bracha": source, please?

Comment: I've always learned that bathroom breaks are a machlokes (or maybe two minhagim?). But definitely not a clear-cut no.

Comment: This is what I recall being taught in yeshiva, I believe based on Chayei Adam.  Will look it up later, b'n.

Comment: I have to look up the sources, but my minhag is to make a bracha only for gedolim, not just being in a bathroom or ketanim.