# Painting Tefillin when you can't Talk

Tags: tefilin

Say you hold that you can't talk in between putting on the Tefillin Shel Yad and the Tefillin Shel Rosh. Right before you put on your Tefillin Shel Rosh, you notice that it has to be painted in a spot that makes it Pasul if not painted. Can you say Leshem Kiddushas Tefillin, or do can you painted it without saying that?

Comment: Seems like the question is just asking "Must you say 'Leshem Kiddushas Tefillin', or do can you paint it without saying that". As the essence of the question, why not just ask that?

Comment: Isn't the bigger question is _painting_ a hefsek? If the painting is a hefsek, the question doesn't start since you need to say a new blessing anyway on the Shel Rosh. Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5142/759

Comment: I am wondering if hirhur doesn't be valuable for "leshem...". Is this a source for haflaa bepeh?